# Spring batch job is already running not working

Tags: spring-batch

I am using spring batch 5. I need to stop running the batch again if it is already running. I have tried bellow like

1. Job config:

   ```
       @Component
       @RequiredArgsConstructor
       @Slf4j
       public class RtgsJob {
         private final ProcessorStep1 batchProcessorStep1;
         private final WriterStep1 batchWriterStep1;
         private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
         private final JobRepository jobRepository;

         public Job createEft(){

               return new JobBuilder("RTGS-STEP1", jobRepository)
                       .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                       .start(step1())
                       .build();


           }


           private Step step1(){

               return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
                       .<input, output> chunk(10, transactionManager)
                       .reader(new ReaderStep1())
                       .processor(batchProcessorStep1)
                       .writer(batchWriterStep1)
                       .build();
           }


       }
   ```
2. Job Schdule run the job:

   ```
       @Component
       @Slf4j
       public class ScheduledJobBean {

           @Autowired
           JobLauncher jobLauncher;

           @Autowired
           RtgsJob eftJob;

           @Autowired
           private  JobRepository jobRepository;

            @Scheduled(cron = "*/30* * * * *")
           public void perform() throws Exception
           {
               JobExecution lastJobExecutionStep1 = jobRepository.getLastJobExecution("RTGS-STEP1", new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters());

               if (lastJobExecutionStep1 == null || lastJobExecutionStep1.getStatus().isLessThan(BatchStatus.STARTING)) {

                   log.info("{} batch step1 {} executionTransaction {} Started ");

                   try {

                       JobParameters jobParameters2 = new JobParametersBuilder()
                               .addLong("startAtRTGSStep1", System.currentTimeMillis())
                               .toJobParameters();
                       executionTransaction =   jobLauncher.run(eftJob.createEft(),jobParameters2);



                   } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException |
                            JobParametersInvalidException ex) {

                       log.error("{} rtgs batch {} Step1 {} executionTransaction {} JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException message: "+ex.getMessage());
                       ex.printStackTrace();


                   }catch (Exception ex) {

                       log.error("{} rtgs batch {} Step1 executionTransaction {} error: "+ex.getMessage());
                       ex.printStackTrace();
                       log.error(ex.getMessage());


                   }
               }else{
                   log.info("{} rtgs batch step1 {} execution {} isRunning ");
               }



           }
       }
   ```

My job started after 30 second. if one job is running it won't start again until it is completed. That means if data process need more than 30 second it won't start again. After completed pressing it will start within 30 second again

But above configuration batch start again within 30 second if one batch is already running.

What is the wrong of my configuration?

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because every time the job is started with a different job parameter which is the current time and the way of retrieving the last job execution with `jobRepository.getLastJobExecution("RTGS-STEP1", new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters())` uses a different set of parameters.

What is happening is that you are creating a new job instance every time and never checking if the past job instance is currently running or not. What could help in your case is probably `JobExplorer#findRunningJobExecutions`.